# Unable To Load Torch_TensorRT module compiled on C++ Visual Studio 2019, in Python

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, torch, tensorrt

I've tried to run torch_TensorRT on ubuntu and windows as well. On windows I compiled it with [this](https://github.com/gcuendet/Torch-TensorRT/tree/add-cmake-support) pull request and it is working good on C++. The resulting trt_module on ubuntu is loading flawlessly on python and can be saved and loaded from disk for future use. This is not the case with Windows C++ module, the resulting trt_model on windows via C++ program is working perfectly with C++ but it is not getting loaded on python. My question is, python library is using C binaries to perform this task and resulting model is getting loaded on python, why it is not same in other case? Am I missing something?

### What I have tried

#### Working

##### Compiling and Loading TRT Model On Python Ubuntu:

```
trt_model_fp32 = torch_tensorrt.compile(torch_script_module, truncate_long_and_double=True,
                                            inputs=[torch_tensorrt.Input((1, 3, 8, 290, 290), dtype=torch.float32)],
                                            enabled_precisions=torch.float16, 
                                            workspace_size=1 << 34,
                                            require_full_compilation=True,

                                            )
torch.jit.save(trt_model_fp32, "NewTRTModel.ts")
model = torch.jit.load("NewTRTModel.ts")
```

#### Not Working

##### Compiling TRT Model On C++ Windows and then Loading on Python:

```
    const torch::Device device = torch::Device(torch::kCUDA, 0);
    torch::jit::script::Module model;

    std::cout << "Trying to load the model" << std::endl;
    try {
        model = torch::jit::load(model_path, device);
        model.to(device);
        model.eval();
    }
    catch (const c10::Error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    auto inp = std::vector<int64_t>{ 1, 3, 8, 290, 290 };
    auto input = torch_tensorrt::Input(inp);
    auto compile_settings = torch_tensorrt::ts::CompileSpec({ input });
    compile_settings.enabled_precisions = { torch::kFloat16 };
  
    // Compile module
    std::cout << "Compiling..." << std::endl;
    auto trt_mod = torch_tensorrt::ts::compile(model, compile_settings);
    // Save module for later
    trt_mod.save("/NewTRTModel.ts");

#### Loading On Python: 
model = torch.load("NewTRTModel.ts")   //throws error
model = torch.jit.load("NewTRTModel.ts") //throws error
```

### Error

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model = torch.load("NewTRTModel.ts")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:711, in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    707             warnings.warn("'torch.load' received a zip file that looks like a TorchScript archive"
    708                           " dispatching to 'torch.jit.load' (call 'torch.jit.load' directly to"
    709                           " silence this warning)", UserWarning)
    710             opened_file.seek(orig_position)
--> 711             return torch.jit.load(opened_file)
    712         return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    713 return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\jit\_serialization.py:164, in load(f, map_location, _extra_files)
    162     cpp_module = torch._C.import_ir_module(cu, str(f), map_location, _extra_files)
    163 else:
--> 164     cpp_module = torch._C.import_ir_module_from_buffer(
    165         cu, f.read(), map_location, _extra_files
    166     )
    168 # TODO: Pretty sure this approach loses ConstSequential status and such
    169 return wrap_cpp_module(cpp_module)

RuntimeError: 
Unknown type name '__torch__.torch.classes.tensorrt.Engine':
  File "code/__torch__/movinets/models.py", line 4
  __parameters__ = []
  __buffers__ = []
  __torch___movinets_models_MoViNet_trt_engine_ : __torch__.torch.classes.tensorrt.Engine
                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
  def forward(self_1: __torch__.movinets.models.MoViNet_trt,
    input_0: Tensor) -> Tensor:
```

### Environment

Windows 11

CPU : i9-11980HK  x86-64

GPU : RTX 3080 Mobile

Cuda : 11.5.2

Cudnn : 8.3.1

Libtorch : 1.11

Tensor_RT : 8.4.1.5

Visual Studio 2019

#### Additional Work

I got help from a person he told me:

To use Torch-TensorRT in Python without importing the Python API you can load libtorchtrt_runtime.so through torch.ops.load_library which will pull in the TorchScript interpreter extensions in order to deserialize and run compiled modules.

I found this file at "python3.8/site-packages/torch_tensorrt/lib/libtorchtrt_runtime.so" on a linux machine where torch_trt was installed via pip, I then tried to load it on windows as suggested however it broke with error as below

```
File "\video_play.py", line 189, in get_torch_tensorrt_converted_model torch.ops.load_library("libtorchtrt_runtime.so") File "C:\Users\NomanAnjum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\_ops.py", line 255, in load_library ctypes.CDLL(path) File "C:\Users\NomanAnjum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__ self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: `.so` files are not portable, you will need a corresponding DLL file to use it on Windows.

Comment: I have corresponding .dll file however I'm not sure how to load it so it works similar to torch.ops.load_library